# From a Flux component function, how to access an input's value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, flux

Simple question from a Flux noob trying to learn...

Let's say I want to define in my App component a simple function that does this :

```
on buttonA.click, send the value of textboxB
```

How do I do this, can I simply refer to an input from the render method's in the `testSend` function?

I looked at [this example](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-todomvc/js/components/TodoTextInput.react.js), but it seems overly complex for my simple need. Do I really have to create another component for each textbox that I want to eventually send the value of through a button click?

Here is my component :

```
export default class App extends Component {
    testSend: function( evt ) {
        // Here I want to send the textboxB.value
        //AppActions.add({ name: '...' });

    },

  render: function() {
    return (
        <input type="text" id="textboxB" />
        <button id="buttonA" onClick={ this.testSend }>Send Text</button>
    );
  },
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: @Mathletics I don't know the syntax  I would need to use

Comment: Do you want to have a single click function you can use with all text boxes on the page?

Comment: @HalHelms no I would like a function that I can bind to a button and reference any input from it, to send values

Comment: I'm still guessing here about what you want to do, but you can put a `ref` on any input and then get the value of any of those from your click function. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Mathletics' remark was meant to points towards the solution ;)

<s>I just can use plain javascript syntax, for once! :D</s>

```
testSend: function( evt ) {
    alert(document.getElementById('textboxB').value);
    //AppActions.add({ name: '...' });

}
```

Solution is to properly use props and state, thanks for the discussion and help!

```
var App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
    return { username: this.props.username };
  },

    changeStateUsername: function( e) {
        //alert(e.target.value);
        this.setState({username: e.target.value});
    },

  render: function() {
    return (
        <input type="text" id="textboxB" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.changeStateUsername} />
        <button id="buttonA" onClick={ this.setNewUsername }>Set</button>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: This isn't "the react way" though; you really shouldn't be dealing with the DOM directly in React.

Comment: @Mathletics thanks for your comment, what would be the React way? Creating a component per textbox as the example linked, and saving the state of each in the props at each keystroke? I would like to use the React way if you can help! :)

Comment: Per @HalHelms comment, https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html; this example covers both how to manipulate the value and how to correctly refer to nodes. The only reason I don't post this as an answer is that the "right" patterns in React seem to be changing pretty rapidly (insert your own _flux_ pun here) and thus an answer is likely to go out-of-date quickly.

Comment: @Mathletics : thanks!  By reading a bit more about it, I believe I should be using the state for that kind of thing...right? as in binding the textbox value to a state property in the controller class

Comment: Yes; think of the rendered element with a value displayed as just that: a display. The actual data you're working with should be stored as state in the component.

Comment: @Mathletics : One last question...how to adequately use the setState function when the value has to come from the user keyboard? The example [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html) simply switches an already existing value in the state, but how to handle it when the value comes from an input's value?

Comment: Look at the link I posted again; the `handleChange` method does what you want.

Comment: @Mathletics : thanks for the help! I posted my final version, let me know if there are still clumsy usages :)

Comment: Your `setNewUsername` function looks unnecessary and frankly _scary_.